# program option linking error boost library with 1.66 version

Tags: c++, boost

I am working on one project where I need to compile all our backend c++ applications from centos to rhel8 Linux machine. I am facing a boost program option error with the boost 1.66 version which comes preloaded in rhel8. If I use boost 1.63 it works for me but mt library. mt library is not available in boost 1.66 version. So i made few changes in makefile. Please find below the difference of make file between 1.63 and 1.66 boost. I am getting program option linking error . Please help me to solve this issue.

working command-line compilation with boost 1.63.

> /usr/bin/g++ -o /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/bin/linux5_64_DBG/toolset -g  -export-dynamic -Wl,"-(" /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/tools/linux5_64_DBG/KevlarToolSet.o /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/tools/linux5_64_DBG/KevlarToolSetMain.o /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/tools/linux5_64_DBG/KevlarJournalEditorTool.o /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/tools/linux5_64_DBG/KevlarQueryCheckpointTool.o /home/rhel8/allan/dev/cure/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libcureapplication.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/eqmon/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libeqmon-mt.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/eqcyclopsmon/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libeqcyclopsmon.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/ivcom/src/linux5_64_DBG/libivcom.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/gslog/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libgslog-mt.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/gscpputil/linux5_64_DBG/libgscpputil.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/pcre/linux5_64/lib/libpcre.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/pcre/linux5_64/lib/libpcrecpp.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/gscushmdb/linux5_64_DBG/libgscushmdb.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/hermes/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libhermescommandmanager.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/hermes/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libhermescommon.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/ivshmdb/api/linux5_64_DBG/libivshmdbapi.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/ivshmdb/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libIvShmDbUserEnums.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/ivshmdb/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libivshmdbcommanddefinition.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/ivshmdb/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libIvShmDbUserRecords.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarapplication.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarcurrenttime.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarcommandlinetools.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlardatastreampair.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarflightrecorder.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarjournalmanager.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarmessagewrapper.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarreplicator.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarresources.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarsharedmemoryutils.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlartransaction.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlaruniqueid.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libKevlarUserEnums.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarcommanddefinition.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libKevlarUserRecords.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libUserRecords.a -Wl,"-)" /home/rhel8/allan/boost_1.63/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.a /home/rhel8/allan/boost_1.63/lib/libboost_regex-mt.a /home/rhel8/allan/boost_1.63/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.a /home/rhel8/allan/boost_1.63/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.a /home/rhel8/allan/boost_1.63/lib/libboost_system-mt.a -lexpat /home/rhel8/allan/dev/pcre/linux5_64/lib/libpcre.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/pcre/linux5_64/lib/libpcrecpp.a /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so  -pthread -Xlinker -ldl -ltirpc -lutil -lrt
>
> /home/rhel8/allan/boost_1.63/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.a /home/rhel8/allan/boost_1.63/lib/libboost_regex-mt.a /home/rhel8/allan/boost_1.63/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.a /home/rhel8/allan/boost_1.63/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.a /home/rhel8/allan/boost_1.63/lib/libboost_system-mt.a

non working command line compilation with boost 1.66

> /usr/bin/g++ -o /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/bin/linux5_64_DBG/toolset -g  -export-dynamic -Wl,"-(" /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/tools/linux5_64_DBG/KevlarToolSet.o /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/tools/linux5_64_DBG/KevlarToolSetMain.o /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/tools/linux5_64_DBG/KevlarJournalEditorTool.o /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/tools/linux5_64_DBG/KevlarQueryCheckpointTool.o /home/rhel8/allan/dev/cure/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libcureapplication.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/eqmon/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libeqmon-mt.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/eqcyclopsmon/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libeqcyclopsmon.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/ivcom/src/linux5_64_DBG/libivcom.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/gslog/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libgslog-mt.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/gscpputil/linux5_64_DBG/libgscpputil.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/pcre/linux5_64/lib/libpcre.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/pcre/linux5_64/lib/libpcrecpp.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/gscushmdb/linux5_64_DBG/libgscushmdb.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/hermes/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libhermescommandmanager.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/hermes/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libhermescommon.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/ivshmdb/api/linux5_64_DBG/libivshmdbapi.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/ivshmdb/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libIvShmDbUserEnums.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/ivshmdb/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libivshmdbcommanddefinition.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/ivshmdb/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libIvShmDbUserRecords.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarapplication.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarcurrenttime.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarcommandlinetools.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlardatastreampair.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarflightrecorder.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarjournalmanager.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarmessagewrapper.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarreplicator.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarresources.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarsharedmemoryutils.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlartransaction.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlaruniqueid.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libKevlarUserEnums.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libkevlarcommanddefinition.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libKevlarUserRecords.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/kevlar/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libUserRecords.a -Wl,"-)" -lboost_filesystem -lboost_regex  -lboost_program_options -lboost_date_time -lboost_system -lexpat /home/rhel8/allan/dev/pcre/linux5_64/lib/libpcre.a /home/rhel8/allan/dev/pcre/linux5_64/lib/libpcrecpp.a /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so  -pthread -Xlinker -ldl -ltirpc -lutil -lrt

```
-lboost_filesystem -lboost_regex -lboost_program_options -lboost_date_time -lboost_system -lexpat
```

this library are available in /usr/lib64 folder with so extension.

Below is the error when i compile with boost 1.66

Error after compiling with 1.66 boost version

> /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarCommandLineToolSet.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISt6vectorISsSaISsEEcEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISt6vectorISsSaISsEEcEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool) const' /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarCommandLineToolSet.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscEE]+0x38): undefined reference to` boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocatorstd::string > const&, bool) const'
> /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarCommandLineToolSet.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const' /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarCommandLineToolSet.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE]+0x30): undefined reference to` boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
> /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarCommandLineToolSet.o): In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >, char>::name() const': /usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:22: undefined reference to` boost::program_options::arg'
> /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarCommandLineToolSet.o): In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::string, char>::name() const':/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:22: undefined reference to` boost::program_options::arg' /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarCommandLineToolSet.o): In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::string, char>::xparse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&) const':/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:184: undefined reference to` boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocatorstd::string > const&, std::string*, int)' /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarCommandLineToolSet.o): In function `void boost::program_options::validate<std::string, char>(boost::any&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >*, int)': /usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:149: undefined reference to` boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocatorstd::string > const&, std::string*, int)' /usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:153: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::invalid_option_value::invalid_option_value(std::string const&)' /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarCommandLineToolSet.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to` boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const' /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarCommandLineToolSet.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const' /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarCommandLineTool.o): In function` KevlarCommandLineTool::KevlarCommandLineTool(std::string const&, std::string const&)':/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/commandLineTools/KevlarCommandLineTool.cpp:12: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)' /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarCommandLineTool.o): In function` boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser::basic_command_line_parser(int, char const* const*)': /usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/parsers.hpp:44: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&)' /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarCommandLineTool.o): In function` std::vector<std::string, std::allocatorstd::string > boost::program_options::to_internalstd::string(std::vector<std::string, std::allocatorstd::string > const&)': /usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/convert.hpp:79: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::to_internal(std::string const&)' /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarJournalEditor.o): In function` KevlarJournalEditor::KevlarJournalEditor(CureApplication*)': /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/commandLineTools/KevlarJournalEditor.cpp:36: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)' /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/commandLineTools/KevlarJournalEditor.cpp:36: undefined reference to` boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)' /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarJournalEditor.o): In function `boost::program_options::validation_error::validation_error(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t, std::string const&, std::string const&, int)': /usr/include/boost/program_options/errors.hpp:378: undefined reference to` boost::program_options::validation_error::get_template(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t)' /usr/include/boost/program_options/errors.hpp:378: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::error_with_option_name(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, int)'/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarJournalEditor.o): In function` boost::program_options::variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const': /usr/include/boost/program_options/variables_map.hpp:155: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const' /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarJournalEditor.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIicEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIicEE]+0x38): undefined reference to` boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocatorstd::string > const&, bool) const'/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarJournalEditor.o): In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<int, char>::name() const':/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:22: undefined reference to` boost::program_options::arg' /home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarJournalEditor.o): In function `void boost::program_options::validate<int, char>(boost::any&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, int*, long)':/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:95: undefined reference to` boost::program_options::invalid_option_value::invalid_option_value(std::string const&)'/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarJournalEditor.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarJournalEditor.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to` boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarShmDatabaseUtility.o): In function `KevlarShmDatabaseUtility::KevlarShmDatabaseUtility()':/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/commandLineTools/KevlarShmDatabaseUtility.cpp:38: undefined reference to` boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/commandLineTools/KevlarShmDatabaseUtility.cpp:38: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/commandLineTools/KevlarShmDatabaseUtility.cpp:38: undefined reference to` boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarShmEditor.o): In function `KevlarShmEditor::KevlarShmEditor(CureApplication*)':/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/commandLineTools/KevlarShmEditor.cpp:278: undefined reference to` boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/commandLineTools/KevlarShmEditor.cpp:278: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarLogQueryTool.o):/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/commandLineTools/KevlarLogQueryTool.cpp:113: more undefined references to` boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)' follow/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarLogQueryTool.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIjcEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIjcEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool) const'/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarLogQueryTool.o): In function` boost::program_options::typed_value<unsigned int, char>::name() const':/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:22: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg'/home/rhel8/allan/dev/timer/lib/linux5_64_DBG/libtimercommandlinetools.a(KevlarLogQueryTool.o): In function` void boost::program_options::validate<unsigned int, char>(boost::any&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > > > const&, unsigned int*, long)':/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:95: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::invalid_option_value::invalid_option_value(std::string const&)'collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Can you include the errors in text. It's really hard to use like this.

Comment: really sorry. i will edit the post

Comment: i have edited the post removed error text image and added the text itself

Comment: Please do not post **any** pictures of text. Post text as text.

Comment: i again edited and removed all images

Comment: Can you take a look at the symbols that program_options exports in `/usr/lib64`? So for example the `options_description` constructor with string,unsigned,unsigned with something like `nm -gD /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options.so | grep options_description 
`. Make sure to look if it's using a different ABI for the std::string for example (i.e. cxx11 abi)

Comment: It looks like you might be compiling with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`, or bringing your .o files over from a machine with an older version of rhel/centos.

Comment: i got to kow that pre loaded version of boost in rhel 8 has not compiled with -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 macro.  Because of this my application were failing.. I compiled the boost library with that macro and everything went fine. thanks.